# Prevent the user from typing while the computer is typing

Tags: python-3.x

This question seems like a duplicate, personally, but I have a few special conditions that limit those questions to help me. Currently, I am using this bit of code to have the computer look like it's typing:

```
def slow_type(y): #slow typing to make it seem like the computer is typing
  for x in y:
        sys.stdout.write(x)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(random.random(     )*10.0/wpm)
      print (' ')
```

I would like to prevent users from typing or making any keystrokes while the computer is typing. Adding it to this function would be optimal, but not neccessary.

Comment: You should look at the readchar package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/readchar.

  You can use it to intercept the user keystrokes (and prevent them typing).  The keystrokes can be queued up and used for input after the "computer" is through typing.

Comment: at the very least, you can examine the readchar code to see how to intercept and get the individual keystrokes.

Comment: so you're saying i could use ascii values? or type out every individual key on the keyboard?

Comment: What I am saying is that to stop the user from typing while the "computer" is typing, you can intercept the keyboard input with your own input routine.  What you do with the user input is up to you.. perhaps just ignore it (until it is the user's turn to type)?  I am addressing the portion of your objective to "to prevent users from typing or making any keystrokes while the computer is typing."